# Connecting App Service to Load Balanced cluster in different Resource Groups

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, networking, elastic-stack

I have 2 separate resource groups in Azure:

1. Contains some Services including a Linux App Service hosting Python Django
2. Contains an ElasticSearch cluster which I created using the ARM template from [here](https://github.com/elastic/azure-marketplace)

I want to connect from the App service in (1) to the ElasticSearch service load balancer in (2)

I tried to create a virtual network peering using

`az network vnet peering create -g $webResourceGroup -n web2es --vnet-name vnet --remote-vnet $remote_vnet --allow-vnet-access`

where `$webResourceGroup => (1)` and `$remote_vnet => (2)`

However, when I try to do an HTTP request to the ElasticSearch Service, it just does not work.

How do I fix or troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some [requirements and constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-manage-peering#requirements-and-constraints) for virtual network peering.

> Resources in one virtual network cannot communicate with the front-end
>   IP address of a Basic internal load balancer in a globally peered
>   virtual network. Support for Basic Load Balancer only exists within
>   the same region. Support for Standard Load Balancer exists for both,
>   VNet Peering and Global VNet Peering. Services that use a Basic load
>   balancer which will not work over Global VNet Peering are documented
>   [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-faq#what-are-the-constraints-related-to-global-vnet-peering-and-load-balancers).

So, if the peered VNets are in a different region, you cannot connect to resources that are behind a `Basic` Load Balancer through the Front End IP of the Load Balancer. This restriction does not exist for a `Standard` Load Balancer. From the [parameters](https://github.com/elastic/azure-marketplace#parameters), you will see that `loadBalancerInternalSku` or  `loadBalancerExternalSku` is by default `basic`, you should use a `standard` load balancer.

[image]

Also, you should have [integrated your app with an Azure Virtual Network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet). Please note that you cannot reach resources across global peering connections(VNets are located in different regions) when you are using [Regional VNet Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#regional-vnet-integration) which requires the app and the VNet must be in the same region. If so, you need to use [Gateway required VNet Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#gateway-required-vnet-integration) and [VNet peering with gateway transit](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/updates/gateway-transit-support-global-vnet-peering/).

If possible, you could create all resources like VNet, app service, cluster in the same region. Then you do not need a VPN gateway for your VNet Integration. This may have fewer limitations and easier to deploy in your scenario.

Hope this could help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I forgot to mention that all the App Services are Linux and one of my colleague just read that _Peering is not yet available for Linux based App Service._, is this the case? what are the alternatives? - here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet

Comment: Virtual network peering is used to make networking connectivity between resources in both VNets. Peering is not related to your app service, but you need a standard or above pricing tier for your networking feature in the app service.